# Spring Security Logging Access Denied Exception

Tags: logging, spring-security, log4j

I have an application with Spring Security which currently does not log access denied exceptions. I'm trying to figure out what setting I need to change in my log4j config to make the access denied exceptions get logged.

I am currently using the default [org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.html) as my AccessDeniedHandler (with one parameter for errorPage). Do I need to create a replacement or inherit from the existing AccessDeniedHandler? Or is there a setting like logExceptions = true that I could add to the AccessDeniedHandler?

Or is there some log4j logger setting that I need to change? I currently have the following setting:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=WARN
```

Answer (score 1):

The configured log-level is too high. Access denied exceptions will be logged in level `DEBUG`:

```
2018-07-18 16:15:09.802 DEBUG 30380 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    [..]
```

So add a logging rule like `org.springframework.security.web.access=DEBUG` to see it.